# Fabric Unity3d Dashboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

The problem is that I can't get into the dashboard of Fabric. 
Even I Didn't get a API key. Everytime I go to the website of fabric it will go to https://www.fabric.io/onboard and i have to install it, but in unity it says: "Click on your app icon to go to the Crashlytics dashboard". And it also said that i need to build the app because I complete the setup progress, but Crashlytics doesn't seem to work. Even when I build the game.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot add an app manually. When you build an app, Fabric will add it into your account automatically as long as your Fabric configuration is right. So check your Fabric settings. Something must be wrong there.

Comment: Do you have any idea what i did wrong or what could go wrong?

Comment: Double check your key and follow the steps provided in Fabric's website. Bu sure that you copied your key from your dashboard not from the tutorials.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Were you able to bring in the Fabric assets into the first scene of your app?

Comment: Hi mike. sorry that i answer so late, but i installed fabric again at the project and now crashlytics is working. I dont know what i did wrong but i tried it over and over and finally it was working.